# How to customize a linux iso's installer?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iso

I am trying to customize my own linux distribution based on Debian using pinguy.

When i generate a .iso for the distribution, i get a default installer which i want to customize by adding certain types of installations for the user to select, like for example :

- Minimal installation
- Installation with list of packages A
- Installation with list of packages B

I also want the installation to give hand to the user to select manually some packages.

How can i achieve that ? 
Thank you.

**Edit** : I need to change this list into a custom one with my own corresponding packages

[image: Debian select packages]

Answer (score 0):

Text based installers are build with bash scripts using tools like `dialog` or the more lightweighted `whiptail`.

Some whiptail examples could be found [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)

**EDIT**:
This is just for building a user interface. You have to deal with users choices, by starting commands like `cp` (copy) or run programs with different switches. I guess ubuntu/debian is using this or something similar. You could take their installer sourcecode and modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is for applications right ? By installer, i mean the installer that is used to install the OS.

Comment: The thing is i need an OS installer. The procedure of creating a user, choosing packages... etc But i can't find how to modify an already existing installer.

Comment: You can create users with `useradd`, you can install packages with `dpkg`. Sources for the debian installer are here: https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team good luck!

Comment: The thing is, i need to change what shows at the installation. I need to change the tasks listed [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs04.html.en#preseed-pkgsel) into my own which correspond to my own lists of packages.